# How can I return to the top of main()?

Tags: java, methods

In my CustomiseParts method, there is an option where the user can return to the beginning of the program again, yet I am not sure how to execute this. All of the necessary code is below, how would I make it so the user can return to the top main() again?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Login();
        AssignBudget();
        CustomiseParts();
      }
```

Comment: Surround those three method calls with a `while(exit_condition)` where `exit_condition` is a boolean expression that needs to be `false` to end the loop. Or use `true` to make it loop indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CustomiseParts` method could return a `boolean` indicating if the program must do another loop or not:

```
do {
    Login();
    AssignBudget();
} while(CustomiseParts());
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need, is to transfer everything the main method does, to another method and call it in main:

```
public class main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        someMethod();
   }

  public void someMethod(){
        login();
        assignBudget();
        customiseParts();
   }

  public void customiseParts(){
        //....your code
        //the option to return to the beginning of the program again
        if(....){
           someMethod();
        }
   }
}
```

This way you can return to the start whenever you want, just by calling the someMethod().

Comment: Beware! Java doesn't perform tail call elimination and this kind of approach may very well cause a stack overflow in the long run.